$A$-module structure of $S^{-1}A$ module determines $S^{-1}A$ module structure uniquely
Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity and $S$ a multiplicative subset. I am trying to show that the forgetful map on $S^{-1}A$ modules is injective. In other words, suppose $M$ and $M'$ are $S^{-1}A$-modules that are the same as $A$ modules. Then how do we show that their $S^{-1}A$-module structure is the same as well?
Let $m \in M = M'$ (as sets), $a \in A$, and $s \in S$. I know that we can say $(a/s) \cdot_M m = s^{-1} \cdot_M(am)$ and $(a/s) \cdot_{M'} m = s^{-1} \cdot_{M'}(am)$ where $am = a\cdot_M m = a \cdot_{M'} m$, but I can't convince myself that  $s^{-1} \cdot_M(am)$ and $s^{-1} \cdot_{M'}(am)$ have to be the same. I know I can multiply by $s$ to get
$$ s \cdot (s^{-1} \cdot_M (am)) = am = s \cdot (s^{-1} \cdot_{M'} (am))$$
and so, letting $m_1 = s^{-1} \cdot_M (am)$ and $m_2= s \cdot (s^{-1} \cdot_{M'} (am))$, we have a scenario where in the shared $A$-module structure, $$sm_1 =s m_2.$$ But I know it is still not true in general for a module over an arbitrary ring that we can then cancel the $s$ and conclude $m_1 = m_2$.
I know I have to be overcomplicating this somehow, getting confused by the $\cdot_M$ and the $\cdot_{M'}$, but I can't seem to convince myself that $m_1$ has to equal $m_2$ and that the $S^{-1}A$-module structure is the same. Can someone help me with this?

It is bad categorical practice to talk about "the same" for modules. You will confuse yourself less by rephrasing the problem in terms of two $S^{-1} A$-modules $M, M'$ such that their restrictions to $A$-modules are isomorphic, so that you can explicitly name the isomorphism $\varphi$. Then you can do it by showing that $S^{-1} A$-modules are equivalent to the full subcategory of $A$-modules on which $S$ acts invertibly.

I see. Then would "injectivity" look something like this? Suppose $\varphi: M \to M'$ is an isomorphism of $A$-modules. Then is it right that what we want to show is that $\varphi$ considered as an $S^{-1}A$-module morphism is also an isomorphism?

An isomorphism of modules is just a module homomorphism that's bijective, so if it is an $S^{-1} A$-module homomorphism at all, it's automatically an isomorphism. The content is to show that $\varphi$ is necessarily also an $S^{-1} A$-module homomorphism.

I'll give it a try: if $\varphi$ is an $A$-module homomorphism, then it is a $S^{-1}A$-module homomorphism as well since $\varphi((a/s) m) = a \varphi(m/s) = (a \varphi(m))/s = (a/s) \varphi(m)$, where we have used in the second equality that $s \varphi(m/s) = \varphi(s(m/s)) = \varphi(m)$ so that $\varphi(m/s) = \varphi(m)/s$. Is this it?

Yes, but it's not really necessary to discuss $a$, so only that second set of calculations matters.

Alright! Thanks for your help. I see now we have shown that the forgetful functor is fully faithful.

This question discusses something with which I usually have problems too, so let me put the comments above in the form of an actual answer for completeness. :)
A(n illustrating) rewording of the problem is that given two $S^{-1}A$-modules that are isomorphic as $A$-modules, we want to show that they are isomorphic as $S^{-1}A$-modules too. Well, as Qiaochu Yuan says in the comments, once put in these terms, it is much clear that one just has to prove that such an $A$-module isomorphism is also an $S^{-1}A$-module isomorphism. Because in the end, an $S^{-1}A$-module isomorphism is an $S^{-1}A$-module homomorphism that is bijective (and we already have bijectivity by hypothesis).
As OP does in the comments, one observes that an $A$-module homomorphism between $S^{-1}A$-modules is also an $S^{-1}A$-module homomorphism because
$$\varphi(a/s)/1=s\varphi(a/s)/s=\varphi(sa/s)/s=\varphi(a/1)/s.$$
So that's it. This reminded me about an exercise I thought about last week: if $M$ and $M'$ are $S^{-1}A$-modules, then $M\otimes_A M'$ and $M\otimes_{S^{-1}A} M'$ are isomorphic as $S^{-1}A$-modules. A similar argument is necessary to proof that $a\otimes_A b\mapsto a\otimes_{S^{-1}A} b$ is a well defined $S^{-1}A$-module isomorphism. Bijectivity then is clear.
Edit: check the comments below, added by Geoffrey Trang and OP, where they explain this phenomena in more general (categorical) terms.

This happens because localizations are epimorphisms in the category of commutative rings. In fact, the same facts that tensor products of $B$-modules are the same regardless of whether the tensor product is over $A$ or over $B$ and $A$-linear maps between $B$-modules are automatically $B$-linear are more generally true for any epimorphism $A \to B$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4936658/tensor-products-remain-unchanged-along-ring-epimorphisms).

@GeoffreyTrang I see! Thanks!

Thank you for consolidating our discussion into a formal answer. I appreciate the time you've taken to write this. Something to note is that what we've done here is show that the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Mod}{S^{-1}A} \to \mathrm{Mod}A$ is fully faithful, making $\mathrm{Mod}{S^{-1}A}$ a full subcategory of $\mathrm{Mod}A$. Since localization of $A$-modules is defined using an universal property construction, we can then conclude that the localization functor $\mathrm{Mod}{A} \to \mathrm{Mod}{S^{-1}A}$ is left adjoint to the forgetful functor.

@mijucik you're welcome! Thanks for your remark, putting it in those terms is very enlightening.
