Do tensor products remain unchanged along ring epimorphisms?
Given any two commutative rings $R$ and $S$ and a ring homomorphism $f:R \to S$, is it true that the obvious surjection $M \otimes_R N \to M \otimes_S N$ is an isomorphism for every two $S$-modules $M$ and $N$ if and only if $f$ is an epimorphism in the category of commutative rings?
It is known that the restriction of scalars functor from $S$-modules to $R$-modules is fully faithful if and only if $f$ is an epimorphism.
For one direction, let $M=N=S$. Then, $S \otimes_R S \to S \otimes_S S \cong S$ is just the multiplication map, and of course, that is an isomorphism if and only $f$ is an epimorphism.
What about the other direction?

Yes. The easiest way to see this is to write everything in terms of tensor products over $S$, which means $M \otimes_R N$ is rewritten
$$M \otimes_S \left( S \otimes_R S \right) \otimes_S N$$
and we want to know when the multiplication map $m : S \otimes_R S \to S$ induces an isomorphism to $M \otimes_S S \otimes_S N \cong M \otimes_S N$. But now it should be clear that a necessary and sufficient condition is that $m$ is itself an isomorphism: this condition is necessary by setting $M = N = S$ as you've already observed, and it's sufficient because if $f$ is an isomorphism then it induces a natural transformation which is also an isomorphism. Formally, there's a functor (even a monoidal functor) from the category of $(S, S)$-bimodules and bimodule homomorphisms to the category of functors $\text{Mod}(S) \times \text{Mod}(S) \to \text{Ab}$ and natural transformations, and it sends isomorphisms to isomorphisms.
An alternative and more abstract argument is the following. Suppose $F, G : \text{Mod}(S) \times \text{Mod}(S) \to \text{Ab}$ are functors which are cocontinuous in both variables ("bilinear") and $\eta : F \to G$ is a natural transformation. Then the condition that $\eta$ is an isomorphism is preserved by colimits, and every $S$-module is an iterated colimit of copies of $S$, so $\eta$ is an isomorphism iff $\eta_{S, S} : F(S, S) \to G(S, S)$ is.
These two arguments are related by the Eilenberg-Watts theorem; the category of such cocontinuous functors is in fact equivalent to the category of $(S, S)$-bimodules.
